# When to use exposure delay?

Tags: lens, exposure, image-stabilization, self-timer

I recently found an option "Exposure delay" to minimize vibration. But is it necessary to use when you have VR on the lens? And does it do anything "extra/meaningful" by using both the VR and Exposure Delay?

Answer (score 3):

**Anytime you can afford the delay.** It reduces vibration from the mirror movement which simply means there will be reduced vibration in the system. This is always good, unless, of course, you cannot time your shot in advance beause you are shooting a moving subject.

This does not mean that it *always* needed since there are other sources of vibration such as the photographer's movement, ground shake, a mechanical shutter, the shutter-release (when not wirelessly triggering). Particularly large vibrations like photographer-movements will trump  mirror vibrations in most cases.

Image stabilization reduces movements by counter-acting vibrations. The less vibration there is to start with, the better results you can expect. Those systems are sometimes prone to false positives, so if you turn it off for shooting with a tripod, mirror vibrations will tend to dominate, in which case the shutter-delay mode becomes more useful.

Answer (score 1):

> I recently found an option "Exposure delay" to minimize vibration. But is it necessary to use when you have VR on the lens?

The point of Exposure Delay mode is to wait for the camera to settle after the mirror has been flipped up, and only then open the shutter, because the mirror's movement can cause vibrations. That's especially important for macro shots, where even a tiny movement can represent a large angular change because the subject is close to the camera.

If you're delaying the exposure for the purpose of minimizing vibration, the camera is usually mounted on some fixture (like a tripod) rather than being handheld. And in that case, you typically turn off VR because that can actually create more vibration when the camera is mounted.

Comment: I do not mean by having a long exposure, I mean by setting an Exposure Delay option from Off to On. I tried it, and when I click the shutter, it will essentially shoot like you would have a long exposure. But what is the difference?

Comment: If you are shooting handheld it doesn't matter at all. You're not going to be able to hold the camera steady enough, with or without IS, to worry about the things that "exposure delay" is designed to counteract.

Comment: @Chris Agree with Michael -- this is a feature you use when the camera is fixed. Delaying the exposure doesn't stop your hands from moving, so there's little point in using it handheld.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! But when using a camera on a tripod, you turn VR off (which I've known since before), and you're using a long exposure, what difference will it make with Exposure Delay on? When changing the shutter speed, to a long shutter speed, it will essentially shoot like with Exposure Delay On. I feel kinda stupid, but as some people says, there are no stupid questions.

Comment: The difference is exactly that Exposure Delay inserts a delay between flipping the mirror up and opening the shutter. The purpose is to let vibrations created by the mirror movement die down. It probably *sounds* like what happens with a long exposure because you hear the mirror flip, and then several seconds pass before you hear it flip down. In reality, the actual exposure time may be quite short. Exposure delay is most useful when the time it takes for the camera to settle is a significant fraction of the total exposure time, i.e. it's not so important for a very long exposure.

Comment: Alright. So it's best to use when you are using a tripod along with a short exposure time, so that it would "remove" some of the vibrations caused by the mirror before taking the shot. With a long exposure, lets say, 3 seconds the camera would be able to "settle" from the vibrations that will occur when you press the shutter, so a Exposure Delay settings is not that useful in that kind of situation.

Comment: I can't say from personal experience, but I'd guess that a 3-second exposure might benefit from Exposure Delay. If the delay is about a second, that means that without it the exposure would experience up to a second of vibration that it wouldn't with Exposure Delay turned on. For a 5-minute exposure, on the other hand, that one second of extra vibration isn't going to contribute much to the overall exposure.

Answer (score 1):

When using tripod, it can be harmful for image quality to use VR as it does not guarantee shake absence even when camera is steady (if you imply Nikon's VR). However, certain implementations of stabilisation may be good even with tripod but you need to check it yourself.

When canera is not fixed it may indeed be profitable to use exposure delay (both with and without VR) if the camera shift imposed by shutter button press exceeds the stabilisation limits - it may happen so when either stabilisation is not advanced enough or when camera is too lightweight.

Additionally, the delay used in combination with mirror pre-rising may cancel the smudge caused with mirror which is apparent with some Sony mirrorless cameras (and with some other cameras too).

Comment: How exactly does a mirrorless camera exhibit mirror “smudge”?

Comment: @EricS just mixed the term from DSLRs with MILCs. MILCs can have smudge as well, just not caused by mirror (IIRC).